# Problema al obtener RGB de un Buffered image

Tags: java, imagen, matrices, animación

Estoy intentando obtener los códigos RGB de una imagen pixel por pixel. Para esto, creé una matriz con las mismas dimensiones de la imagen:

```
cargaImagen ImagenCargada = new cargaImagen("SpriteSheet.png");
imagen = ImagenCargada.img;
alto=imagen.getHeight();
ancho=imagen.getWidth();
pixeles = new int[alto][ancho];
```

Luego, para obtener el RGB de cada pixel y guardarlo en mi matriz, uso el siguiente ciclo con la función getRGB:

```
        for(int x=0; x<alto;x++){
        for(int y=0; y<ancho; y++){
            pixeles[x][y]=imagen.getRGB(x,y);
            //System.out.println(imagen.getHeight()+" ancho:"+imagen.getWidth());
        }
    }
```

Pero al compilar me da este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:318)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:917)
at animacion2.pkg0.HojaSprites.<init>(HojaSprites.java:31)
at animacion2.pkg0.Animacion20.main(Animacion20.java:27)
```

Comment: ¿Y de dónde salen *alto* y *ancho*?

Comment: De imagen.getHeight(); y imagen.getWidth();

Answer (score 1):

Acá te presento una manera de poder realizar el análisis que deseas hacer.

```
public void analisisImagen(){

    try {
        BufferedImage imagenMemoria = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/andy/Imágenes/407463-PD558O-40.jpg"));
        int ancho = imagenMemoria.getWidth();
        int alto = imagenMemoria.getHeight();

        System.out.println("ancho: "+ancho+" - alto:"+alto);

       IntStream.range(0, ancho).forEach(x -> {
           IntStream.range(0, alto).forEach(y -> {

               System.out.println("ColorRGB: ("+x+","+y+") "+imagenMemoria.getRGB(x, y));

           });
       });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo cargar el archivo");
        Logger.getLogger(PruebasMultiples.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En ese código que tenés, estás usando X para definir la altura, e Y para el ancho, si bien puede funcionar ya que son solo nombres de variables, al momento de poner image.getRGB(x, y)
Te olvidas que es getRgb(posiciónX, posiciónY)
Que en tu código están invertidos, por lo que tendrías que poner getrgb(y,x).

Te recomiendo que uses x para definir ancho e y para el alto, por que si no pueden pasar problemas asi,.

Si ese no es el problema comentarme que tal.